# Is the effectiveness of a column index related to the entropy of the column data

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, orm, relational-database

As the consumer and occasionally of relational databases (Postgres, MySQL) I often have to consider query speeds in the context of various queries. However often you don't know how a database will be used or where the bottlenecks might be until it's in production.

This makes me wonder, **can I use a rule of thumb about the predicted entropy of a column as a heuristic for guessing the speed increase of indexing that column?**

A quick Google results in papers written by Computer Science graduates for Computer Science graduates. Can you sum it up in "layman" terms for a self taught programmer?

---

**Entropy?**: I'm defining entropy as calculated by number of rows divided by number of times a value is repeated on average (mean). If this is a poor choice of words for those with a CS vocabulary, please suggest a better word.

Comment: The term to search for is cardinality

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know cardinality could be used in that context, I thought it was only used in describing relationships.

Comment: Google & read the site:dev.mysql.com pages re index/indexes/indexing/etc, optimizing/optimizer/etc & efficient/efficently/etc.

Comment: I found [this article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1309cardinal/) from IBM that explains why low cardinality columns can slow query performance as well.

Comment: You should also look up the term "selectivity and how it relates to query conditions on indexes.

Comment: Think about it this way. You have 1M rows and and it's split 50/50 between two values.

Now imagine another table with 1M rows but all unique values in a given field. 

Which index is going to be more useful during a query?

Hint: Postgresql is likely going to ignore the first index since it will be necessary to just read the whole table anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is really too broad to answer thoroughly, but I'll attempt to sum up the situation for PostgreSQL (I don't know enough about other RDBMS, but some of what I write will apply to most of them).

Instead of *entropy* as you propose above, the PostgreSQL term is the *selectivity* of a certain condition, which is a number between 0 and 1, defined as the number of rows that satisfy the condition, divided by the total number of rows in the table. A condition with a low selectivity value is (somewhat counter­ intuitively) called *highly selective*.

The only sure way to figure out if an index is useful or not is to compare the execution times with and without the index.

When PostgreSQL decides if using an index for a condition on a table is effective or not, it compares the *estimated cost* of a sequential scan of the whole table with the cost of an index scan using an applicable index.

Since sequential reads and random I/O (as used for accessing indexes) often differ in speed, there are a few parameters that influence the cost estimate and hence the decision:

- `seq_page_cost`: Cost of a sequentially fetched disk page
- `random_page_cost`: Cost of a non-sequentially fetched disk page
- `cpu_tuple_cost`: Cost of processing one table row
- `cpu_index_tuple_cost`: Cost of processing an index entry during an index scan

These costs are measured in imaginary units, it is customary to define `seq_page_cost` as 1 and the others in relation.

The database collects *table statistics* to so that it knows how big each table is and how the column values are distributed (most common values and their frequency, histograms, correlation to physical position).

To see an example how all these numbers are used by PostgreSQL, look at [this example](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/row-estimation-examples.html) from the documentation.

Using the default settings, a rule of thumb might be that an index will not help much unless the selectivity is less than 0.2.

Answer (score 2):

What I think you are asking is what the impact of an index is relating to the data distribution of data in a column.  There is a bunch of theory here.  In GENERAL, you will find that index lookup efficiency depends on the distribution of data in the index.  In other words, an index is more efficient if you are pulling 0.01% of the table than if you are pulling 5% of the table.  This is because random disk I/O is always less efficient (even on SSDs due to read-ahead caching by the OS) than sequential reads.

Now this is not the only consideration.  There are always questions about the best way to retrieve a set, particularly if ordered, using an index.  Do you scan the ordering index or the filtering index and then sort?  Usually you have an assumption here that data is evenly distributed between the two but where this is a bad assumption you can get bad query plans.

So what you should do here is look up index `cardinality` and get experience with query plans, particularly when the planner makes a mistake so you can understand why it is in error.